# how to use properly decorators?

Tags: python-3.x

i got this bunch of code but i don't know what i'm missing around here.

```
import time

a = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]

b = [[3, 2, 1], [7, 3, 5]]

def timer(f):
    def clock():
        start = time.time()
        f()
        end = time.time()
        print(end - start)
    return clock()


@timer
def multiplication(x, y):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(x[i])):
            print(x[i][j] * y[i][j])

multiplication(a, b)
```

If anyone got something to support, that would be so helpful.

Answer (score 1):

problem solved

```
def timer(f):
def clock(x, y):
    start = time.time()
    f(x, y)
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)
return clock
```

i was missing the two required arguments from 'multiplication'

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is key when it comes to Python in general. And here, I see that the line "import time" isn't rightly indented. It needs to be placed at the extreme left.

As you're probably starting off with Python, I recommend you to go through [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) this page to understand the concept of Indentation.

Comment: i didn't notice that 'import time' over there when i was copying the code, it was some trouble with pasting the code, sorry.